# Button click=unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: java, android

Hi im new to android programming and this code produces an error when the button is clicked... It shows unfortunately the application has stopped can anybody check? :(

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.compute);
    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button06);

    //get intent
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras(); // get the parameters

    density = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int textViewSizeDp = (int)(200 * density);
    int textFieldSizeDp = (int)(50 * density);

    FieldsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.FieldsLayout);
    if(extras!=null){
        items = (extras.getString("items")).split(",");
        rows = new LinearLayout[items.length];
        labels = new TextView[items.length];
        fields = new EditText[items.length];

        for (int ctr=0;ctr<items.length;ctr++){
            rows[ctr] = new LinearLayout(Compute.this);
            rows[ctr].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            rows[ctr].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            rows[ctr].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            FieldsLayout.addView(rows[ctr]);

            labels[ctr] = new TextView(Compute.this);
            labels[ctr].setText(items[ctr]);
            labels[ctr].setMinimumWidth(textViewSizeDp);
            rows[ctr].addView(labels[ctr]);

            fields[ctr] = new EditText(Compute.this);
            fields[ctr].setMinimumWidth(textFieldSizeDp);
            rows[ctr].addView(fields[ctr]);

        }
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }



    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  


        public void onClick(View v) {   

              Intent i = new Intent(Compute.this, Total.class);
              //I believe this causes the error
                for(int ctr=0;ctr<fields.length;ctr++){
                    itemName[ctr] = labels[ctr].getText().toString();
                    }

                for(int ctr=0;ctr<fields.length;ctr++){
                    itemHour[ctr] = Integer.parseInt(fields[ctr].getText().toString());
                    }
                //until here
              i.putExtra("hours",itemHour);
              i.putExtra("items",itemName);
              startActivity(i);
              }});     

}
```

here's the error log: (or is this it?)

```
01-14 09:37:16.047: W/Trace(768): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.mpc.Compute$1.onClick(Compute.java:82)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-14 09:37:16.187: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Does it produce a stacktrace?  If so post it.

Comment: Either `labels[ctr]` or `fields[ctr]` is null. Use a breakpoint to find out which

Comment: will you post the code of Total.java? may be you are not getting the vaulues in activity which u are starting in the right way..! its an array. how you are getting the value?

Comment: ok ill post the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out following things:

1. Make sure your field array is initialized properly.
2. Make sure that the length of `itemName` is same as that of `fields.length` and it should be properly initialized.
3. Make sure that the length of `labels` is same as that of `fields.length` and it should be properly initialized.
4. Make sure that the length of `itemHour` is same as that of `fields.length` and it should be properly initialized.

Comment: what is line 82 in Compute.java?

Comment: Also make sure that all the arrays you are using are properly initialized.

Comment: how do i make sure they are properly initialized?

Comment: LinearLayout[] rows;
 TextView[] labels;
 String[] items;
 EditText[] fields;
 LinearLayout FieldsLayout;
 float density;
 Button aButton;
 String[] itemName;
 int[] itemHour; 
this is how i declared them.

Comment: you need to initialize these like this : labels = new TextView[];
and after that before assigning values to them, you need to initialize every single child like this : labels[i] =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.layout_id); where i is the index of labels array that you are initializing

Comment: In case normall datatypes other than widgets you can simply initialize like thi: itemName=new String[size of string];

Comment: what if it has no index? because the value of length is from the number of records that are dynamically generated depending from the previous class.

Comment: by the way you haven't told yet...what is line 82 in Compute.java?

Comment: its the for loop... i indicated it in the code above. i put in the comment //I believe this causes the error

Comment: 2 things: 1st- try printing fields.length, if its not an issue then 2nd -  initialize itemName like itemName = new String[items.length]; after you have initialized labels array. Same approach with itemHour array

Comment: Thanks... i did some tinkering on those codes and it worked! Your the best!

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. The Id of button
2. Same id more then one button in same layout.
3. Its map with xml file or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer i double checked it and i believe the id is unique

Answer (score 0):

As this is NullPointerException, you are either having some null fields or you have forgotten to initialise some of your fields,

Check,

- If you have done `aButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);`
- if you have initialised `itemName[]` and `itemHour[]`, something like `itemHour[ctr] = new String[];`
- If there are any values in the `labels[]` and `fields[]`

If it still doesnt helps, then you should post some more relavent code, only then I could edit my answer.

Comment: hi i think i properly done 1 and 3... im not sure where to initialize it... my entire code is above.

Comment: What is **itemName[]** and **itemHour[]** and where have you initialised it.?